# Rcpp: error in calling a c++ function from another c++ function

Tags: c++, rcpp

I'm writing my functions in C++ to use them in R. Since I don't want to include all the functions inside the same file, I want to call them. I'll give you a simple example of the three files I'm using:

**function.h**:

```
#ifndef FUNCTION_H    
#define FUNCTION_H

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

arma::vec quadraticsum(arma::vec x);

#endif
```

**function.cpp**:

```
 #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
 #include <function.h>
 // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

 using namespace Rcpp;
 using namespace arma;
 using namespace std;

 // [[Rcpp::export]]

 arma::vec quadraticsum(arma::vec x){
   arma::vec results = sum(pow(x,2));
   return results;
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <function.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::vec sum2(arma::vec x){
  arma::vec results = quadraticsum(x)+2;
return results;
}
```

I'm working with Rstudio and when I write the code in the **main.cpp** file it recognizes the function *quadraticsum*, and so everything seems to be fine. However, when I compile using the command `sourceCpp("~/main.cpp")`, I got this error:

> Error in dyn.load("/private/var/folders/46/1tz_54_n3glfmgftvqsspwrr0000gn/T/Rtmpdnk9hf/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.12/sourcecpp_237a88636e6/sourceCpp_2.so") : 
>     unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/46/1tz_54_n3glfmgftvqsspwrr0000gn/T/Rtmpdnk9hf/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.12/sourcecpp_237a88636e6/sourceCpp_2.so':
>     dlopen(/private/var/folders/46/1tz_54_n3glfmgftvqsspwrr0000gn/T/Rtmpdnk9hf/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.12/sourcecpp_237a88636e6/sourceCpp_2.so, 6): Symbol not found: __Z12quadraticsumN4arma3ColIdEE
>     Referenced from: /private/var/folders/46/1tz_54_n3glfmgftvqsspwrr0000gn/T/Rtmpdnk9hf/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.12/sourcecpp_237a88636e6/sourceCpp_2.so
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /private/var/folders/46/1tz_54_n3glfmgftvqsspwrr0000gn/T/Rtmpdnk9hf/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-0.12.12/sourcecpp_237a88636e6/sourceCpp_2.so

Have you seen this problem before? I'm using macOS 10.12.5. Thank you all.

Comment: If you have several files (or even just several functions), consider writing a package. `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` does all the work for you.

Answer (score 3):

`sourceCpp` only allows a single source file.

If you want to use multiple source files, you will need to build a full package.

The error appears because the second source file has not been compiled or linked into the shared library. As a result, no function implementation exists.

You could also make the implementations `static` or `inline` and then place them in a header, of you want to avoid a full package. if

Comment: So if I want to modify my code including `static` or `inline`, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that writing `#include "function.h"` instead of `#include <function.h>` it compiles correctly. I just changed it. Thank you all.